# Extract object from Woocommerce payload and remove backslashes from the string

Tags: javascript, json, regex, woocommerce, aws-lambda

I am trying to access an object (tmp_name) within a Woocommerce webhook payload in AWS Lambda. At the moment I can output the "line item" with:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback, err) => {
    callback(null, event.line_items);
    if (err) console.log('JSON Pass Fail');  // an error occurred
    else     console.log(event.order_key); // successful response
};
```

When I try to go deeper into the event data it runs as null, such as

`callback(null,event.line_items.meta_data.value.tmp_name);`

I have tried accessing the array with 0 and [0] with no joy either.

Eventually if I can access the file path, i need to strip out the backslahes so it looks like a proper file path. I have got the regex for that which is `string.replace(/\\\//g, "/");`

Can anyone help me put this together?

```
{
"line_items": [
    {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Audio 5",
    "product_id": 15,
    "variation_id": 0,
    "quantity": 1,
    "tax_class": "",
    "subtotal": "10.00",
    "subtotal_tax": "0.00",
    "total": "10.00",
    "total_tax": "0.00",
    "taxes": [

    ],
    "meta_data": [
        {
        "id": 20,
        "key": "_wcj_product_input_fields_global_1",
        "value": {
            "name": "Aaron Ramsey's departure from Arsenal to Juventus.mp3",
            "type": "audio\/mp3",
            "tmp_name": "\/home\/site\/public_html\/wp-content\/uploads\/woocommerce_uploads\/wcj_uploads\/input_fields_uploads\/21.mp3",
            "error": 0,
            "size": 4943085,
            "wcj_type": "file"
        }
        }
    ],
    "sku": "",
    "price": 10
    }
],
"tax_lines": [

],
"shipping_lines": [

],
"fee_lines": [

],
"coupon_lines": [

],
"refunds": [

]
}
```

Comment: `const removeBackslash = (obj) => obj.line_items[0].meta_data.map((meta) => {
  return meta.value.tmp_name.replace(/\\/g, "")
})` a simple function like that will return an array of urls without backslashes. Is that what you need?

Comment: I can access that object now, strangely when I paste the payload into the Lambda test area the \/ gets removed. So if it passes through API gateway like this perhaps it is not needed. But have the correct syntax to grab that tmp_name now. Thanks